# How to detect message content Discord.js?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js, bots

I am working on a code for a Discord bot for my server, and I'm currently stumped on a magic 8 ball feature, go figure. I'm trying to get it to check if there is a message after the 8 ball command, and if not, send a message to the same channel telling the user to supply it a message to answer.

This is my code:

```
if (commandName === '8ball') {
          message.author.get(args[0]);
      const message = args.join(' ').slice(0);
      if (message.length < 10) message.channel.reply; 'You need to give me a question to anser, bud.';

      const messages = [
         '8ball messages here'  
      ];
      const pEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
          .setTimestamp('')
          .setColor(`${bedcolor}`)
          .randomMessage = messages[Math.floor(Math.random() * messages.length)];
      return message.reply(pEmbed);
```

It returns an error saying it cannot access message before initialization, and is also doesn't embed despite the code being there. I'm new to Javascript and I'm kind of attempting to splice random code together to make it work, so I'm probably doing something very wrong here. I'd appreciate anyone's advice on how to at least make this code function and to learn more about JS so I don't have to 'splice' random code.

Comment: It's only natural to learn JavaScript before using a JavaScript library like DiscordJS. Regardless you're redefining message which may be causing conflicts within the scope of the code you've shown. Rename the second `message` to anything else. There's also major syntax errors such as `reply; '...'` and `() .randomMessage = '...'`. I highly recommend you learn JS if you plan to get far in development, it will make your work alot easier in the long run

Comment: Why are you chaining a `.randomMessage` function on your pEmbed, that is not an accepted function to use on `Discord.MessageEmbed()`.  Also on line 4 of the code you call `message.channel.reply` which is not an accepted method on channels, also you put a semicolon after it then the text to send instead of calling it as a function with the text to send passed to it. So even if it was an existing method it would just error since you didnt actually invoke it, the proper way to do that would be `message.reply('You need to give me a question to answer, bud.')`. I agree with @Elitezen, learn JS.

Answer (score 0):

Considering that you are on Discord V13, you would need to do
`message.channel.send({embeds: [pEmbed]})`
for it to function, instead of
`message.channel.send(pEmbed)` its a new feature to the Version 13 addition.

You would also need to do
`randomMessage = messages[Math.floor(Math.random() * messages.length)];`
and then state `` .setDescription(`Answer: ${randomMessage}`) `` as an example

Happy coding! Let me know if you run into issues.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```js
function someFunctionName() {
    var messages = ['...','...']
    return messages[Math.floor(Math.random()*rand.length)];
}

const pEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
          .setColor(`${bedcolor}`)
          .setDescription(someFunctionName())
      return message.reply(pEmbed);
```